# Simplifying this expression

Tags: combinatorics

[image: the expression]

Is there any simplified version of x.

Comment: Hint: Draw out the pascal triangle, what pattern can you observe for k=1,2,3,.. ? Prove your result by induction.

Comment: And use latex, it hadn't ever hurt anyone

Comment: @enedil [Latex allergy?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latex_allergy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^k\binom{n+i-1}{i}=\sum_{i=1}^k\binom{n+i-1}{n+i-1-i}$ //Complement $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$

$=\sum_{i=1}^k\binom{n+i-1}{n-1}$

$=\binom{n-1}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n+1}{n-1}+\dots+\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}=\binom{n+k}{n}$

// Recursively using [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule)  and complement.